# While trying to display an error message that there is a browser instance already open, unable to do the validation

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Functionality:
A new browser window opens while user clicks on a command link. We have achieved this functionality using Request Context in the bean class.
Now when the user goes back to the main window, and clicks on the command link again, an error message should be displayed stating that there is already a browser instance running.
We are unable to do this. Below is the code

```
<p:commandLink id="contactUs"
               style="display: block;text-decoration: underline;color: #0099CC !important;"
               value="#{prop.contact_us_label}" 
               actionListener="#{bean.openWindow}">
</p:commandLink>
```

```
requestContext.execute("window.open('" + <<page>> + "','abc','" + windowParameters + "')");
```

Comment: Just open a p:dialog instead?

Comment: @BalusC: According to the requirement a new browser window should be opened with the necessary information.

Comment: Communitate back that this requirement is an UX killer.

Comment: Is there no way out?

Comment: I didn't said it's impossible. It's just an UX killer.